# Include PHP and CSS files -> relative path

Tags: php, css, path, include, relative-path

Hello how can I include PHP and CSS files from another directory to the current file? [Open Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k33m0.png)

Include in mathe.php the files from php and css.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Look at the way `session.php` is included with `../php` relative paths and same for styles.css. You would need to use the same way to import other files.

Comment: Hi, for the PHP files you may define a constant containing the absolute path to the project regarding the file system (e.g. for Windows `const ROOT_DIR = 'C:\wamp\www\your-project';` or Linux `const ROOT_DIR = '/home/user/www/your-project';`) then you prepend it to the `include` directive `include ROOT_DIR . '/php/navigation.php'`. For the CSS it's another story, the absolute paths are relative to the Apache document Root defined for your project, if you used a virtual host it the path should be `/css/style.css`, if you don't use a virtual host the path should be `/your-project/css/style.css`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `php` directory lies two levels below the `mathe.php` script. You can do something like:

```
include(__DIR__ . '/../../php/navigation.php');
```

To include the CSS files, I would start by specifying a `<base>` tag, that will properly anchor all relative URIs. The CSS files are read through the webserver, and will depend on what URL the document root is mapped to.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this in a few ways. One would be to create some rules to route a request to a certain path or directory to a php file.

Route directory/foo.css to foo.php

In foo.php file you could use something like this:

```
header("Content-Type: text/css"); 
header("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff"

requrire('path-to-file1.css);
requrire('path-to-file2.css);
```